# argparse not overriding default value

Tags: python, arguments, argparse

I managed to write some simple Python code using values from .csv to create an .svg file.
However argparse does not "pass" a value from command line - I'm not able to override the default.
I want to define [c]/[columns] with command line.

```
import argparse
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser("svg.py")
parser.add_argument("-c","--columns",help="number of columns (default=20)",default=20)
args = parser.parse_args()
```

when I run

```
svg.py -c 24
```

the value is still 20.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you have an error in argument passing. Here my working example

`svg.py`

```py
import argparse
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser("svg.py")
parser.add_argument("-c","--columns",help="number of columns (default=20)",default=20)
args = parser.parse_args()
print(args.columns)
```

It runs correctly

```
$ > python svg.py -c 24
24
```

Hope this helps to figure out the problem

Comment: Wow, that was fast! I believe the problem was elsewhere. After adding type=int to the argument creation line it all works as expected

Comment: @TomaszBiernacki Happy to help, and welcome to Stack Overflow. If this answer or any other one solved your issue, please mark it as accepted.